# Why are my TextViews acting strangely?

Tags: android, textview

I'm making a rather pointless android app that has two buttons, and two textviews.

It has a counter int set to 0.

The fist button named add, adds 1 to the counter, the second button named sub, subtracts one from the counter.

If the counter is greater than 1, the totalPlus textview is shown, with the current counter value.

If the coutner is equal to 0 or less, the totalMinus textview is shown, with the current counter value.

In both cases, the non-relevant textview is hidden.

The problem I'm having is that, say I'm on +5, the top counter will shown, and it will be seen incrementing when I press the button. But if I press the subtract button, the current textview hides, until I get to 0 or less in which the minusTextView displays. It works both ways.

[code]

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    totalPlus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalPlus);
    totalMinus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalMinus);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            counter++;

            if (counter > 1)

               totalPlus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               totalMinus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               totalPlus.setText("Your Total is " + counter);

        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            counter--;

            if (counter <0)

               totalMinus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               totalPlus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               totalMinus.setText("Your Total is " + counter); 
        }
```

Comment: Your if counter calls aren't wrapped in brackets so it is performing the second and third statement no matter what. Wrap your if content in brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java ignores indentation levels. You need to use braces around all three statements which you want to be executed if the `if` statement passes.

```
if (counter <0) { // <-- this
    totalMinus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    totalPlus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    totalMinus.setText("Your Total is " + counter);
} // <-- and this
```

If you do not include these braces, Java only considers the first statement to be part of the `if` construct; the other two statements are outside that construct and will execute always.

Comment: Thank you!

You say Java ignores indentation levels. Are there languages which don't?

Comment: Python does to an extent.